# Dónde ubicar el INSERT...SELECT en un FOR para unas facturas con Python y MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

Intento generar en MySQL varios registros múltiples con 'INSERT...SELECT' en una tabla llamada 'facturas' de unos 8 arrendatarios con Python.

```
#CONSULTA DEL VADOR DEL IVA JURIDICO
cursor.execute("SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;")
dato1 = cursor.fetchall()
#CONSULTA DE LA INFORMACION DE LOS ARRENDATARIOS
cursor.execute("SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;")
dato2 = cursor.fetchall()
connect.commit()
for a in dato1:
    ivaj = a[0] #16.0 (float)
    print ivaj
    for i in dato2:
        if i[4] == 2:
            #showinfo("","Es Jurídico")
            iva = i[3]*ivaj/100 #vl arriendo*iva/100
            total = i[3]+iva
        else:
            #showinfo("","Es Natural")
            iva = 0
            total = i[3]+iva
    try:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) SELECT c_cod, now(), '%f', '%f' FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;''' % (iva, total))
        connect.commit()
    except:
        pass
  showinfo('Operación', "Grabado!")
```

En la primera consulta se busca el valor de un impuesto llamado IVA Jurídico en una tabla llamada 'configuracion' que contiene un único valor flotante (16.0) y que se aplica a aquellos arrendatarios que son tipo jurídico.

```
MariaDB> SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;
+-------------+
| ivajuridico |
+-------------+
|          16 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Luego, se busca la información necesaria de los arrendatarios y los inmuebles en varias tablas relacionadas. El resultado de esta son 8 registros ya que ese es el total de los arrendatarios que hay en la base de datos. Una de ellos, el primero es tipo jurídico.

```
MariaDB> SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| c_cod | now()               | i_cod | i_vlrenta | a_tpersona |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1509 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |  1140 |   5284240 |          2 |
|  1526 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   170 |    687500 |          1 |
|  1528 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |    88 |    432000 |          1 |
| 22736 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   386 |   1338000 |          1 |
| 22754 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   192 |    720000 |          1 |
| 22789 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |  1144 |    645000 |          1 |
| 22898 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   448 |   3700000 |          1 |
| 22900 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   449 |   1100000 |          1 |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lo demás creo que es entendible, porque consiste en difinir que si un arrendatario es tipo jurídico entonces se le aplica el valor del iva jurídico, de lo contrario el valor 0.

Sin embargo, el código restante, donde está el `try:`, que es donde debo hacer el INSERT...SELECT... tengo problemas, porque me arroja 8 registros con el mismo valor de arriendo para todos los arrendatarios y con valor de IVA 0, donde en realidad uno de ellos es jurídico. Pero, si ubico el código del `try:` debajo del `else` obtengo 64 registros en lugar de 8.

```
mysql> select * from factura_Arre;
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
| fa_num | c_cod | fa_fecha            | fa_iva | fa_total | fa_estado | fa_notas |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
|     40 |  1509 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     41 |  1526 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     42 |  1528 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     43 | 22736 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     44 | 22754 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     45 | 22789 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     46 | 22898 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     47 | 22900 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

El punto es donde debería ir entonces el `try:` o qué más código me hace falta para que funcione?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema de lógica, por un lado haces un bucle para calcular el total según el iva que le corresponde a cada arrendatario, pero el `INSERT` lo tienes afuera de ese bucle y además insertas los 8 registros en batch. Tienes dos formas de resolverlo:

#### Insertando un arrendatario a la vez.

Algo como lo siguiente. Calculas el Iva y el total mediante el código **Python** y por cada registro leído insertas un nuevo registro en `factura_arre`

```
for i in dato2:
    if i[4] == 2:
        #showinfo("","Es Jurídico")
        iva = i[3]*ivaj/100 #vl arriendo*iva/100
        total = i[3]+iva
    else:
        #showinfo("","Es Natural")
        iva = 0
        total = i[3]+iva
    try:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);''' % (i[0], i[1], iva, total))
        connect.commit()
    except:
        pass
```

#### Resolviendo todo en SQL

Otra forma es resolver todo del lado del servidor, sin ningún bucle, lo que de alguna manera has intentado inicialmente. Si te fijas, agregamos un `CROSS JOIN` con la tabla `configuracion` para obtener el `ivajuridico` y mediante un `CASE` si el arrendatario es una persona jurídica, aplicamos dicho iva en el calculo del monto total.

```
try:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) 
                    SELECT  c_cod, 
                            now(), 
                            (CASE WHEN a_tpersona = 2 THEN ivajuridico ELSE 0 END),
                            i_vlrenta * (CASE WHEN a_tpersona = 2 THEN ivajuridico ELSE 0 END) / 100
                            FROM contratos 
                            INNER JOIN relacionip 
                                ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id 
                            INNER JOIN inmuebles 
                                ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod 
                            INNER JOIN arrendatarios 
                                ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;
                            CROSS JOIN configuracion;
                   ''')

    connect.commit()
except:
    pass
```

Espero te sea útil.